# How to get random int values to a prefab which is called multiple times(without repeating same value)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random, duplicates

I have created a prefab which contains text (a*b=) and input field (to get user's answer). and I am calling this prefab 5 times using c# script. I have assigned a & b to random.range(1,10) so i can get 5 different sums. but in my case i am getting same values to all 5 sums.

I tried foreach loop and it is getting random numbers out of given range and on clicking check button it shows even correct answers in red(as incorrect).
This is the first time i am dealing with calling prefab multiple times via script. so need some help to solve it please.

TestModeQuestionUI.cs

```
using Helper.Keyboard;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TestModeQuestionUI : MonoBehaviour
{
internal RectTransform refRectTransform;
[SerializeField]
TextMeshProUGUI valueA; // valueB;
[SerializeField]
MyInputField AnswerInputField;
internal int id;
internal Action<TestModeQuestionUI> onSubmitValueOfInputFieldAction;
internal Action<TestModeQuestionUI> onSelectInputFieldAction;

Color defaultColorOfAnswer = new Color(0.19f, 0.19f, 0.19f, 1f);
Color correctColorOfAnswer = new Color(0f, 0.44f, 0f, 1f);
Color incorrectColorOfAnswer = new Color(1f, 0f, 0f, 1f);

public static TestModeQuestionUI curSelectedAnswerInputField;

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

void Awake()
{
    refRectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
}


private void SetNextAnswerInputFieldAsSelected(TestModeQuestionUI 
curSelectedAnswerInputField)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public void SetQuestionLabel(string v)
{
    valueA.text = v;        
}

public void ActiveAnswerInputField(bool active)
{
    AnswerInputField.gameObject.SetActive(active);
}

public int GetAnswerInputField()
{
    int result = -1;
    int.TryParse(AnswerInputField.textComponent.text, out result);
    return result;
}

public void SetAnswerInputField(string msg)
{
    AnswerInputField.textComponent.text = msg;
}

public void SelectAnswerInputField()
{
    DeSelectCurSelectedAnswerInputField();
    AnswerInputField.ActivateInputField();
    curSelectedAnswerInputField = this;   
}

public static void DeSelectCurSelectedAnswerInputField()
{
    if (curSelectedAnswerInputField != null)
    {            
       curSelectedAnswerInputField.AnswerInputField.DeactivateInputField();   
    }
       curSelectedAnswerInputField = null;
}

public void SetResultOfAnswerInputField(int result)
{
    switch (result)
    {
        //==================================
        // Default Color For Answer Has Not Checked
        case 0:
            AnswerInputField.textComponent.color = defaultColorOfAnswer;
            break;

        //==================================
        // Correct Color For Answer Has Checked Correct
        case 1:
            AnswerInputField.textComponent.color = correctColorOfAnswer;
            break;

        //==================================
        // Incorrect Color For Answer Has Checked Incorrect
        case 2:
            AnswerInputField.textComponent.color = incorrectColorOfAnswer;
            break;
    }
}

public void OnSelectInputField()
{
    //Debug.Log("On Select : " + id);
    if (curSelectedAnswerInputField != this)
        DeSelectCurSelectedAnswerInputField();
    curSelectedAnswerInputField = this;

    if (onSelectInputFieldAction != null)
        onSelectInputFieldAction(this);
}

public void OnSubmitValueOfInputField()
{
    if (onSubmitValueOfInputFieldAction != null)
        onSubmitValueOfInputFieldAction(this);
}

}
```

TestModeManager.cs

```
 public class TestModeManager : MonoBehaviour
 {
 public static TestModeManager instance;
 [SerializeField]
 GameObject refTestModeQuestionExampleParent;
 [SerializeField]
 GameObject refTestModeQuestionExamplePrefab;
 [SerializeField]
 GameObject checkButton;
 [SerializeField]
 GameObject nextButton;

 private int a, b;
 List<TestModeQuestionUI> testModeQuestionExampleList;


 void Start()
 {
    CreateUI();
 }

 void Update()
 {        
 #if UNITY_EDITOR
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.KeypadEnter))
    {    SetNextAnswerInputFieldAsSelected(TestModeQuestionUI.curSelectedAnswerInputField);          



    }
 #endif

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        if (Keyboard.instance.gameObject.activeInHierarchy)
            Keyboard.Close();
        else
            Application.Quit();
    }
 }


 void CreateUI()
 {
    GameObject _GO;
    TestModeQuestionUI _TestModeQuestionUIRefrence;

    if (testModeQuestionExampleList == null)
        testModeQuestionExampleList = new List<TestModeQuestionUI>();

   //  a = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 20);
  //   b = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 10);

    for (int id = 1; id <= 5; id++)
    {
        _GO = Instantiate(refTestModeQuestionExamplePrefab, 
 refTestModeQuestionExampleParent.transform);
        _GO.name = "TestModeQuestion Example " + id;
        _TestModeQuestionUIRefrence = _GO.GetComponent<TestModeQuestionUI> 
 ();
        _TestModeQuestionUIRefrence.id = id;
        _TestModeQuestionUIRefrence.onSubmitValueOfInputFieldAction = 
  SetNextAnswerInputFieldAsSelected;
        testModeQuestionExampleList.Add(_TestModeQuestionUIRefrence);

  }

    ResetUI();               
  }

  void ResetUI()
  {
    // Reset Multiplication Examples
    a = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 10);
    b = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 10);
    foreach (TestModeQuestionUI _TestModeQuestionUIRefrence in 
  testModeQuestionExampleList)
    {
        _TestModeQuestionUIRefrence.SetQuestionLabel(a + " " + b + "  = ");

   //loop to get 5 different sums
   var questions = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("question");
   foreach (var question in questions)
   {
         // a++;
         //b++;
  }

   }
  //==================================
    // Set First Answer Input Field As Selected
    SetNextAnswerInputFieldAsSelected();

  }
  void SetNextAnswerInputFieldAsSelected(TestModeQuestionUI _ 
  TestModeQuestionUIRefrence = null)
  {
    if (_TestModeQuestionUIRefrence == null)
    {
        //==================================
        // Get First Input Field And Set As Selected
        _TestModeQuestionUIRefrence = GettestModeQuestionExampleList(1);
        if (_TestModeQuestionUIRefrence != null)
            _TestModeQuestionUIRefrence.SelectAnswerInputField();
    }
    else
    {
        //==================================
        // Get Next Input Field And Set As Selected
        _TestModeQuestionUIRefrence = 
  GettestModeQuestionExampleList(_TestModeQuestionUIRefrence.id + 1);
        if (_TestModeQuestionUIRefrence != null)
            _TestModeQuestionUIRefrence.SelectAnswerInputField();
        else
        {
            Keyboard.Close();
            StartCoroutine(highlighCheckButton());
        }
    }
  }

  TestModeQuestionUI GettestModeQuestionExampleList(int id)
  {
    foreach (TestModeQuestionUI _TestModeQuestionUIRefrence in 
  testModeQuestionExampleList)
    {
        if (_TestModeQuestionUIRefrence.id == id)
        {
            return _TestModeQuestionUIRefrence;
        }
    }
    return null;
  }
  IEnumerator EnableKeyboardAfterSometime(float time)
  {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    Keyboard.Open();
  }

IEnumerator highlighCheckButton()
{
    checkButton.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f);
    float animtionTime = 0.3f;
    float scaleUpTo = 1.2f;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        yield return AnimationController.animate(scaleCheckButton, 
        animtionTime, 1f, scaleUpTo);
        yield return AnimationController.animate(scaleCheckButton, 
        animtionTime, scaleUpTo, 1f);
    }
    checkButton.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f);
}

void scaleCheckButton(float value)
{
   checkButton.transform.localScale = new Vector3(value, value, value);
}

public void CheckButton()
{
    int answer;
    foreach (TestModeQuestionUI _TestModeQuestionUIRefrence in 
testModeQuestionExampleList)
    {
        answer = _TestModeQuestionUIRefrence.GetAnswerInputField();
        if ((a * b) == answer)
        {
            _TestModeQuestionUIRefrence.SetResultOfAnswerInputField(1);
        }
        else
        {
            _TestModeQuestionUIRefrence.SetResultOfAnswerInputField(2);
        }
    }

    checkButton.SetActive(false);
    nextButton.SetActive(true);
}

public void NextButton()
{
    ResetUI();
    nextButton.SetActive(false);

}
```

Comment: You can create a list with integers ranging from 1 to 10 and then random an index between 0-9 and remove that number from the list then repeat it for random index 0-8. You wont get duplicates

Answer (score 0):

You should get the random value inside the loop, otherwise you get the same values.

```
foreach (TestModeQuestionUI _TestModeQuestionUIRefrence in testModeQuestionExampleList)
{
    int a = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 10);
    int b = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 10);
    _TestModeQuestionUIRefrence.SetQuestionLabel(a, b);
}
```

You also should save `a` and `b` in `TestModeQuestionUI` because they are different betweent instances.

```
public class TestModeQuestionUI : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int a, b;

    public void SetQuestionLabel(int a, int b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        valueA.text = a + " " + b + "  = ";        
    }
}
```

Comment: i added above code in my file. so now i am getting different values but still correct answers are shown in red (marked as incorrect when check button is clicked)

Comment: should i use any loop in CheckButton function too?

Comment: I've said you should save and use `a` and `b` in `TestModeQuestionUI` class, remove them from `TestModeManager`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of UI stuff but if i were you and if i do not want to get duplicates i would create a separate script for getting random values like this:

```
public class RandomIntegers {

   private static List<int> myNumbersA = new List<int>();
   private static List<int> myNumbersB = new List<int>();

   public static void  RandomValues(out int a,out int b)
   {
      if (myNumbersA.Count == 0)
      {
           for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
           {
               myNumbersA.Add(i + 1);
               myNumbersB.Add(i + 1);
           }
       }
       int indexA = Random.Range(0, myNumbersA.Count);
       int indexB = Random.Range(0, myNumbersB.Count);
       a = myNumbersA[indexA];
       b = myNumbersB[indexB];
       myNumbersA.RemoveAt(indexA);
       myNumbersB.RemoveAt(indexB);
    }
}
```

Then in your `ResetUI` function you can call this function using
`RandomIntegers.RandomValues(out a,out b);` The reason why i implemented it this way is instances of your prefab can access it when they are instantiated and since it is static you will not get same random results for a and b. But lets say you might get `6` for `a` and `8` for `b` but also `8` for `a` and `6` for `b` both will result as `48` at the end.

Comment: surely i will keep this in mind. i am ok with getting a and b  same values in sum. just that i want 5 different sums to generate. but now my problem is with check button function. when i am trying to check if user enters correct answer or not by checking a*b. if correct change color to green or else red. at the moment my script is showing even correct answers in red

Comment: earlier when i was getting all same 5 sums check button function was working fine and showing correct answers in green and incorrect in red. now while i am getting random nos, it is not working properly

Comment: It returns Integer

Comment: Can you log what does this `int.TryParse(AnswerInputField.textComponent.text, out result)` give you

Comment: Text of answer input field is converted into int

Comment: I understand that but i wanted to see if it works correctly. If user enters 5 and 5 does it give you 25 there or some other result. If it is not working then the problem is at somewhere else

Comment: Yes it gives me whatever answer user will enter. And check button will perform a check to see if user entered correct or incorrect answer and change text color accordingly

Comment: I understand your intentions but i think you should add lines like this to your code to see what is broken and whether your code works as intended `Debug.Log(int.TryParse(AnswerInputField.textComponent.text, out result))`

Comment: i have updated my question with screenshot just to get an idea of my ui and issue i am facing.please have a look

Comment: Yes it helped but i can't see any problem in your code and i can not reproduce it either so you need to **Debug** your code so that we can understand what is working what is not

Comment: Debug.Log(int.TryParse(AnswerInputField.textComponent.text, out result)) does not show anything in the console.

Comment: Okay it probably means either your `AnswerInputField` is `null` or `AnswerInputField.textComponent` is `null` or the `text` is null.

Comment: yes. does that mean it is not working because i am calling random values?otherwise it works.but gives me same 5 sums

Comment: well you never call `SetAnswerInputField` this method. Why do you have this method. Apparently your `AnswerInputField` value is never set.

Comment: as you suggested,i have  created new separate script for getting random values. and changed resetUI function.i dont know how but now only 5th answer is checked properly and turns green if its correct.

Comment: ya but only last sum 's answer is checked properly. rest 1-4 still shows answers in red.

Comment: I am lost i really do not know why i would suggest adding `Debug.Log` to several places to see what goes wrong